# Discontinuous VLC playback under 13.10

Tags: 13.10, video, vlc

Since system upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 I have discontinuous playback with current vlc player version even for low-mid quality avi files. Tried to reinstall vlc several times using different install methods, installed the restricted extras with codecs also, no success fixing the problem.

Any one experiencing the same? Any ideas how to fix the playback?

Comment: Only VLC or other audio as well? What sound card?

Comment: Generic player is doing just fine, haven't tried others. The soundcard is Sigmatel Audio (Dell latitude D830).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem which is as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ed10vi86/video
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

The version 2.0.8 is problematic for me, 2.1.0 is OK.

Hope this helps.

Comment: with this version the volume control using a mouse wheel doesn't work but still better than 2.0.8 :)